# Pandas drop rare entries

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm new to Pandas. 
To simplify, I have a data frame with two columns: product_id and rating. Each entry is a new review for the given product.
Now I want to get a new data frame in which lines corresponding to the product which received less then 20 reviews (ie. appears less then 20 times in the original data frame) are removed.
I can count the number of occurences with:

```
a = data.groupby('product_id').count()
b = a.loc[a['rating']>20]
```

but that gives me back a 1D data frame. When displayed, each product_id has its count, but I'm unable to access the actual product_id's to use them to filter the original table. For instace,

```
b.values
```

gives back a 1D array of the counts, but no the product_ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
a = data.groupby('product_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 20)
```

Comment: Done! I was also wondering how this works: somehow groupby+count is extremely fast, but filtering is much slower, even though both of them are built in functions.

Comment: Presumably here it has to parse the results of the filtering and build the df from that result whilst for `count` it's just a reduction without having to filter the results afterwards is my guess.